# How to match any of a Vector of strings with nom?

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I'm trying to create a parser with nom that will parse some text that could be one of many options. Nom has `alt!` for when the values are known at compile-time, but my values won't be.

This has been my attempt to create my own parser that can take a `Vec<String>` to match against, and I'm running into a couple issues.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

use nom::IResult;

fn alternative_wrapper<'a>(input: &'a [u8], alternatives: Vec<String>) -> IResult<&'a [u8], &'a [u8]> {
    for alternative in alternatives {
        // tag!("alternative");
        println!("{}", alternative);
    }
    return IResult::Done(input, "test".as_bytes());
}

#[test]
fn test_date() {
    let input = "May";
    named!(alternative, call!(alternative_wrapper));
    let months = vec!(
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
        ).iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", alternative("May".as_bytes(), months));
}
```

I'm aware that my `alternative_wrapper` function doesn't actually do anything useful, but that's not the problem. This is what Rust complains about for this snippet:

```
error[E0061]: this function takes 1 parameter but 2 parameters were supplied
  --> src/parser.rs:32:34
   |
17 |     named!(alternative, call!(alternative_wrapper));
   |     ------------------------------------------------ defined here
...
32 |     println!("{:?}", alternative("May".as_bytes(), months));
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 parameter
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0061]: this function takes 2 parameters but 1 parameter was supplied
  --> src/parser.rs:17:5
   |
6  | / fn alternative_wrapper<'a>(input: &'a [u8], alternatives: Vec<String>) -> IResult<&'a [u8], &'a
[u8]> {
7  | |     for alternative in alternatives {
8  | |         // tag!("alternative");
9  | |         println!("{}", alternative);
10 | |     }
11 | |     return IResult::Done(input, "test".as_bytes());
12 | | }
   | |_- defined here
...
17 |       named!(alternative, call!(alternative_wrapper));
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 2 parameters
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
```

How I can create a parser out of my function? And how I can use existing parsers such as `tag!` from within `alternative_wrapper`?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with the errors, the first error is due to `named!` only taking a single argument, namely the input string. `named!` will declare a function for you, in this case with the signature `fn(&[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8],&[u8]>`. There's no magic regarding any other arguments, so trying to pass your `months` vector as a second argument will not work. There's a variant of `named!` called `named_args!` that can be used to declare functions with more arguments than just the input that should sort that out.

The second error is similar but reversed. You're calling the `alternative_wrapper` with only the input and no vector via `call!`. The `call!` macro can actually pass arguments, but you must do it explicitly, i.e `call!(myparser, monts)`.

With the reasons to the errors sorted out, you're asking about how to create a parser. Well, actually, `alternative_wrapper` is *already* a nom parser by signature, but since you didn't declare it via a nom macro, none of the magic input passing happens, which is why `tag!` doesn't work in the function body when you've tried.

In order to use other combinators in a function that you have declared yourself, you have to pass the input manually to the outermost macro. In this case it's only `tag!`, but if you were to use, say, `do_parse!` and then multiple macros within that, you'd only need to pass the input to `do_parse!`. I'll provide a working version with a few additional tweaks here:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

use std::str;
use nom::IResult;

fn alternative<'a>(input: &'a [u8], alternatives: &Vec<String>) -> IResult<&'a [u8], &'a [u8]> {
    for alternative in alternatives {
        match tag!(input, alternative.as_bytes()) {
            done@IResult::Done(..) => return done,
            _ => () // continue
        }
    }
    IResult::Error(nom::ErrorKind::Tag) // nothing found.
}

fn main() {
    let months: Vec<String> = vec![
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ].into_iter().map(String::from).collect();

    fn print_res(r: IResult<&[u8],&[u8]>) {
        println!("{:?}", r);
        println!("{:?}\n", str::from_utf8(r.unwrap().1).unwrap());
    }
    print_res(alternative(b"May", &months));
    print_res(alternative(b"August", &months));
    print_res(alternative(b"NoGood", &months));
}
```

You can check it out in the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c98b3af5b6d2a96b42b37c32d904afaf&version=stable).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with nom, and still learning Rust, but I have used parser combinators in the past.

Caveats aside, it looks like the `named!` macro generates a function that only takes one parameter, the string to parse.

To satisfy nom's expectations, I think I'd look at writing `alternative_wrapper` as a function that returns a function instead. The test would end up looking like this:

```
#[test]
fn test_date() {
    let months = vec!(
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
        ).iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
    let parser = generate_alternative_parser(months);
    named!(alternative, call!(parser));
    println!("{:?}", alternative("May".as_bytes()));
}
```

It looks like you'd need to construct an `alt!` expression from `tag!`s, but it's not immediately obvious to me from the docs how you'd do that.

Where does your list of options ultimately come from?

Depending on exactly what you are trying to accomplish, there might be some other ways to accomplish what you're trying to do as well. For example, you might be able to parse any word and then validate it against one of your options afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

With Nom 4, here is a fully generic input that works no matter what your parser operates on:

```
/// Dynamic version of `alt` that takes a slice of strings
fn alternative<T>(input: T, alternatives: &[&'static str]) -> IResult<T, T>
where
    T: InputTake,
    T: Compare<&'static str>,
    T: InputLength,
    T: AtEof,
    T: Clone,
{
    let mut last_err = None;
    for alternative in alternatives {
        let inp = input.clone();
        match tag!(inp, &**alternative) {
            done @ Ok(..) => return done,
            err @ Err(..) => last_err = Some(err), // continue
        }
    }
    last_err.unwrap()
}

/// Usage
named!(test<Span, Span>,
    call!(alternative, &["a", "b", "c"])
);
```